# Is it "teleport into" or "teleport in"?

Tags: grammar, meaning

Is it "teleport **into**" or "teleport in"?
Teleport implies a movement and into indicates the destination. Therefore, is "teleport in" incorrect? It seems to me that "teleport in X" means you're teleporting from X. Is this the case or not? Or do both mean the same thing?

For example:

> He teleported in the room.
>
> He teleported into the room.

Comment: Please don't close.  This is not opinion-based -- the verb can be associated with other verbs of motion, along with whatever preposition is appropriate.  Just because we can't *actually* teleport doesn't mean that people haven't been teleporting for close to a century, in fiction.

Comment: Is he teleporting **in the room** - from one location in the room to another? Or is he teleporting **into the room** from some location outside of the room?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When and if teleportation becomes a reality, no doubt specialized language to deal with it will be developed, just as specialized terminology for the telephone and the internet has been. Until then ...

In works of SF where teleportation is used, I have seen "Teleport into X" used where X is the destination, and I have seen "Teleport in from X" used where X was the origin of the trip. i have also seen things like:

> He teleported in unexpectedly.

used without any specification (in that sentence) of origin or destination.

---

A sentence such as

> He teleported in the room.

would mean: "He teleported from one part of the room to another", or so i would expect.

Comment: Couldn’t it also mean that “he began his teleportation in the room,” the room being the place where the teleportation happens?

Comment: @med It could, but that seems less probable to me. With no context, and no pattern of real use to compare to, one cannot be at all sure.

Answer (score 5):

I think your question has very little to do with the specific word *teleport.* I think that the use of prepositional phrases is pretty similar for all verbs of motion. But note that the usage of prepositions is an area where there is often variation between speakers or between dialects.

> It seems to me that "teleport in X" means you're teleporting from X. Is this the case or not?

No, I wouldn't use "in" to mean "from".

With verbs of motion, I think a prepositional "in [noun phrase]" usually implies that the entire path of the moving object (or person) is in [noun phrase]. For example, "I jogged in the park" means that I was in the park for the entire time that I was jogging. (I might have jogged outside of the park also, but the sentence doesn't refer to that jogging.)

Occasionally, a speaker might use "in" in place of "into". I wouldn't recommend doing this, but for example, I can imagine the sentence "Sam walked in the room" being used to express "Sam walked into the room". Here are some discussions about that use of "in":

- [Preposition: She walked <in, into> the living room](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/preposition-she-walked-in-into-the-living-room.652345/). (WordReference)
- [Which is grammatically correct: "I walked into my room" or "I walked in my room"?](https://www.quora.com/Which-is-grammatically-correct-I-walked-into-my-room-or-I-walked-in-my-room) (Quora)

In contrast, I cannot imagine "Sam walked in the room" ever being used to mean "Sam walked out of the room" or "Sam walked out from the room".

Answer (score 2):

To add on to the other answers:  Since we can't actually "teleport" at this point in time, we have to imagine what prepositions would make sense with similar actions, such as *enter*, *travel*, *jump*, *appear*, *move*, *walk*, *run*, and various others.

For example, you could write it as if they had suddenly appeared *in* the room.  Or you could envision they moved *in to* the room. Or that they journeyed *to* the room *from* some other location.  Or *onto* some location where that preposition is common:

> Skipping protocol, the captain teleported directly **onto** the bridge of his ship.  "Make ready to set sail, Mister Christian," he called to the first mate.  "There is no time to lose!"

Almost any preposition is possible, as long as the resulting action makes sense to the reader.

> While the main force engaged the rebels from the front, a small strike team teleported **behind** the front lines, quickly subduing their commanding officer.